# C# create HttpClient based on existing Stream

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, dotnet-httpclient

I have established a secure connection to a web server using BouncyCastle TlsClientProtocol and it gave me a System.IO.Stream which I can read and write to, the following code works:

```
        MyTlsSession sess = new MyTlsSession("api.telegram.org", 443);

        using (var stream = sess.Stream())
        {
            var hdr = new StringBuilder();
            hdr.AppendLine("GET / HTTP/1.1");
            hdr.AppendLine("Host: api.telegram.org");
            hdr.AppendLine();

            var dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hdr.ToString());
            stream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);

            int totalRead = 0;
            string response = "";
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            do
            {
                totalRead = stream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                response += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff, 0, totalRead);
            } while (totalRead == buff.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
```

How can I instantiate a System.Net.Http.HttpClient on top of this Stream to have a higher-level API instead of dealing with raw bytes?

I don't use built-in TLS capabilities of .NET because of an outdated OS (doesn't have the required cipher suites).

Comment: Check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers). I think it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string CallTCP(string domainName, int port)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        string result;
        TcpClient client;

        Logger.Verbose("CallTCP Connecting", ">>" + domainName);
        client = new TcpClient(domainName, port);

        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

        int recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
        Logger.Verbose("CallTCP Connect\t", "<<" + domainName + "->" + result);


        ns.Close();
        client.Close();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error("CallTCP", "Error: \t" + e.Message.ToString());
        Logger.Error("CallTCP", "Error: \t" + e.StackTrace.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post just code, please include explanation as well.